# Can you automatically update product stock to Woocommerce from a merchant center feed?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-shopping

We'd like to use a shared inventory from 3 sites running on opencart and one new site running on Wordpress. We have a Google Merchant Center / Shopping feed that updates automatically.

Is it possible to update our woocommerce stock and products using this feed?

I can only find info on exporting products from Woocommerce to shopping.

Comment: Have a look at this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Comment: Thanks, I think that should work. Going to test it asap :-)